# ORA-00903: invalid table name error

Tags: database, oracle

I am an SQL Rookie, I am trying to create a table but I have this error.

```
CREATE TABLE User
(
  UserID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  UserName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  Email varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  MembershipInfo varchar(50),
  MembershipRank varchar(50),
  CatID int,
  CONSTRAINT CatID FOREIGN KEY(CatID) REFERENCES Category(CategoryID)
)
```

Comment: user is a reserved word to oracle change it to users

Comment: You can still enclose the name in double quotes.."User".. but, the side effect is.. you have to always refer it with double quotes from then.

Answer (score 3):

`USER`is a [reserved word in Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a42525/apb.htm) and can't be used as a table name. The solution is to use another name.

Answer (score 3):

`USER` is a [reserved word](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e10830/appb.htm). While it may be technically possible to force the database to let you create a table using a reserved word, it's a really bad idea. Just pick a new name - `USERS` is popular for this reason.